# ParallelParameterized - how to save test results in parallel for each input in same order as input?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, concurrency

```
@RunWith(ParallelParameterized.class)
public class RoutingResponseShortRegressionOneByOne {

    private int numberOfProcessedRequests;
    private Object currentRequestIndexLock = new Object();


    @Test
    public void compareNewResponseToBaselineReturnsNoLargeDifferences() throws IOException {

        int currentRequestIndex;
        synchronized (currentRequestIndexLock) {
            //currentRequestIndex = e2EResultShort.completeRoutingResponses.size();
            currentRequestIndex = numberOfProcessedRequests;
            numberOfProcessedRequests++;
        }
```

I try to run this code

and I see `numberOfProcessedRequests == 0` in every run, and doesn't increment as I would expect from class member.

It's a `ParallelParameterized Test`.

Why does it create a new Test Class instance for every input?

I see the ctor is called only once.

Should there be a different way to run the test in parallel for each input and still maintain the order of the results as the order of the input?

Comment: JUnit, by design, [creates a new class instance for each test method](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html). Can you expand a little on your last paragraph, since this appears to be the meat of your question?

Comment: then why do i see the testClass constructor `RoutingResponseShortRegressionOneByOne ` is called once when I debug?

Comment: regarding my last paragraph: I want to run the test for 1K input lines. The test calculates a result. I want to save the results in the same order of the input. eg input1, result1. input2, result2. and so on... I thought I can do this in parallel but still keep the results order somehow. (I can create a fix size array as I know the size of the results)

Comment: Please don't provide additional information in comments. You should [edit] your question and make the question itself better. You can assume that almost every comment is a request for you to edit your question, rather than reply as another comment.

Comment: It's hard to say why your test constructor is called once, with the limited code you've posted. Perhaps you're not splitting your input up like you think you are? The constructor should be called once for each of your pieces of input data.